# How to allow write access on a directory to java/tomcat in debian buster

Tags: java, java-11, file-writing, tomcat9, debian-buster

I made a fresh install of debian buster with tomcat9 package.

I want to deploy GeoWebCache application (latest 1.15 version) on it, and it require a directory with read and write access in order to store config files, generated cache, ...

I create the directory /opt/gwc_cachedir and set 777 permissions on it :

`# chmod -R 777 /opt/gwc_cachedir`

And put my config file (geowebcache.xml) in the directory also with 777 permissions.

When starting the tomcat instance, the logs says that the /opt/gwc_cachedir directory is not writable :

`ERROR [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - Found Java environment variable GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR set to /opt/gwc_cachedir/ , which is not writeable`

It seems to be caused by a call to canWrite function which return false :

https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/blob/f921c79adc24783cc445cf3ba0349b9bcd2a2421/geowebcache/core/src/main/java/org/geowebcache/storage/DefaultStorageFinder.java#L134

I don't understand why it return false as the /opt/gwc_cachedir has 777 permissions.

### SOLVED

The problem was with systemd service definition, I need to allow the tomcat to read and write to the directory

Adding this line to `/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service` do the job :

```
ReadWritePaths=/opt/gwc_cachedir
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user or group which is used to run tomcat9 process are not allowed to write to your cache directory.

Inspect `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service` to see which group and user will tomcat process run as.

Most likely it's

```
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
```

... in which case just change the owner of your cache directory to `tomcat`:

`sudo chown -R tomcat: /opt/gwc_cachedir/`

OR it's Java's Security Manager stopping access... solution still pending...

Comment: As I said, I set permission with 777.
I also tried to chown the directory and his content to tomcat user, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: can you verify the user's access to your directory? call `sudo -u tomcat test -w /opt/gwc_cachedir/; echo $?` and see if you get ZERO as in success. This obviously checks the **WRITE** access for **tomcat** user

Comment: I tried your command, and it return 0, so it seems that the problem is with java or tomcat, not with system.

Comment: cool, try moving your cache to java tmp folder to see whether it could be Java's Security manager. If so you will also have to modify `catalina.policy` to add your folder into there with write permission. Check here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html

Comment: I tried to edit /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/conf/security/java.policy adding : 

permission java.io.FilePermission "/opt/-", "read,write,delete";
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "readFileDescriptor,writeFileDescriptor";
permission java.io.SerializablePermission "enableSubstitution,enableSubclassImplementation";

But I still have the same error.

Comment: I also tried with permission java.security.AllPermission; but it still sayin that the directory isn't writeable

Comment: did you try turning debug on for security to see some more details? `export CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.security.debug=all`

Comment: Tried to add this option, it add a lot of info in logs, but nothing seems to be related to this problem.